# compile printing a string function give error message - C

Tags: c, string, printf

i want to write a simple main function in C that receive two line of string input and prints them on the screen.
this is the code i wrote:

```
int main()
{
    char a[100];
    char b[100];
    printf("Enter the first string:\n");
    fgets(a,100,stdin);
    printf("Enter the second string:\n");
    fgets(b,100,stdin);
    printf("\n\n THE FIRST STRING IS:  %S\n\n THE SECOND STRING IS:%S",a, b);
    return 0;
}
```

and when i try to compile, i get this error message:

```
gcc -g -Wall PN52.c -o myprog
PN52.c: In function ‘main’:
PN52.c:12:2: warning: format ‘%S’ expects argument of type ‘wchar_t *’, but argument 2 has type ‘char *’ [-Wformat]
PN52.c:12:2: warning: format ‘%S’ expects argument of type ‘wchar_t *’, but argument 3 has type ‘char *’ [-Wformat]
```

Thanks for helping

Comment: Keep the good habit of passing `-Wall` to `gcc`  !!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You use `%S` format, whereas the format for strings (`char*`) is `%s`.

```
printf("%s - %s\n", a, b);
```

Answer (score 3):

Replace uppercase `%S`  by lowercase `%s` in `printf` format string.

Comment: No, the `-Wall` option of `gcc` made you find that mistake really quickly

Answer (score 0):

just replace %S by %s as C is case-sensitive that's why you have to take care of these things